# I need a dictionary text file with meanings

Tags: python, dictionary

I need a text file in the form:

aardvark : animal
atlas : collection of maps
.
.
.
.
.
and so on.

I want to use this text file to create my own dictionary like Artha or Wordweb.It will be Python based with Tkinter for GUI.

Where can I obtain such a file.

Answer (score 1):

[Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/etext/673) has a few variants (including the unabridged Webster's). Not exactly the format you're looking for, but you should be able to parse it to remove parts of speech, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/).

Yes, this is a large complex library because the task is actually complex. `aardvark: animal` is easy; given `hit:` what do you put after it? Do you mean the noun, the verb, or the adjective? Which sense of the noun? Did the baseball player make a hit? Did the pop star have a hit? Did the hit baseball player hit the hit with his bat?

**added:**

```
#!/bin/sh
# tersify - returns the most terse definition for its input
#
# examples: echo "aardvark" | tersify
#           tersify < /usr/share/dict/words > ~/my_dict

while  read word  ; do
   echo "$word: $word"
done
```

'tis a joke, take thee not offense

Comment: That is a pertinent issue. I guess for now I am looking for a simple database of words,with the most terse meaning possible.